# Please explain the ui repeat class difference in JSF API IMPL 2.1.7 AND 2.2.14

Tags: java, user-interface

In jsf api impl jar 
 class using hashmap in 2.1.7 version , but in 2.2.14 version it is using 
both hashmap and concurant  hashmap.

Can some one please explain the difference.

I am using jsf 2.1.7 version my code giving error in uirepeat.

When multiple uirepeats are used in single page it is giving high cpu utilization.

```
<ui:repeat></ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Fix spelling and code formatting. Add [java] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in jst 2.1.7 version ui repeat is implemented with the hashmap, where as in 2.2.4 it is implemented with concurrent hashmap.
if you are using JSF 2.1.7 version better dont use the ui repeat.
inplace of ui repeat please use the JSTL for each.
or else upgrade your JSF version to 2.2.4 later.